# InputAccessoryView causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS on UITextview resignFirstResponder

Tags: ios

I'm using an inputAccessoryView with a next and a done button, to help manage to keyboard. However, I've run into a problem, where every so often the app will crash with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when the keyboard is being closed with resignFirstResponder.

The code that I'm using is below

```
- (void)keyboardNextClicked {
    int i = 0;
    for(ALFReportField *field in _reportfields) {
        UITextView *textView = field.txtvValue;
        if(textView.isFirstResponder) {
        if(_reportfields.count > i + 1){
                ALFReportField *nextField = _reportfields[i + 1];
                [nextField.txtvValue becomeFirstResponder];
            }
            else {
//                [textView performSelector:@selector(resignFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.125];
                [textView resignFirstResponder];
            }
            return;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

-(void)keyboardDoneClicked {
    for(ALFReportField *field in _reportfields) {
        UITextView *textView = field.txtvValue;
        if(textView.isFirstResponder) {
//            [textView performSelector:@selector(resignFirstResponder)  withObject:nil afterDelay:0.125];
            [textView resignFirstResponder];
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The commented lines was an attempt to resolve the problem by delaying the resignFirstResponder call (a solution that I read about elsewhere), but it didn't work.

The app runs through the code without problem, down to the return, throwing no errors in my code. However, just after it has exited by code, I get an error with the following stacktrace:

```
objc_retain + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1178f8b9)
    frame #0: 0x33b5067a libobjc.A.dylib`objc_retain + 10
    frame #1: 0x26c3e1fa UIKit`-[UIResponder _preserveResponderOverridesWhilePerforming:] + 122
    frame #2: 0x27125230 UIKit`-[UIInputWindowController invalidateInputAccessoryView] + 112
    frame #3: 0x27125b58 UIKit`-[UIInputWindowController changeToInputViewSet:] + 972
    frame #4: 0x271208a2 UIKit`__77-[UIInputWindowController moveFromPlacement:toPlacement:starting:completion:]_block_invoke886 + 414
    frame #5: 0x268e59b4 UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 540
    frame #6: 0x268e5494 UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 204
    frame #7: 0x268e538e UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 78
    frame #8: 0x2617aa50 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 252
    frame #9: 0x3425bbd6 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 22
    frame #10: 0x34269f70 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1524
    frame #11: 0x2277e96c CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
    frame #12: 0x2277ce66 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1574
    frame #13: 0x226d0118 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
    frame #14: 0x226cff04 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
    frame #15: 0x2b886ac8 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 160
    frame #16: 0x26912f14 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 144
  * frame #17: 0x000eee44 Alfix app`main(argc=1, argv=0x00584a48) + 108 at main.m:14
```

Anyone have any idea what is going wrong? I'm not touching the textviews in any way, shape or form during this process, except for the resignFirstResponder call. That, coupled with the stacktrace makes me think that it must be InputAccessoryView that is causing the error.

Edit:

The input accessory view is created through the general override method on the viewcontroller's view:

```
- (UIView *)inputAccessoryView {
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 36);
    UIView *inputAccessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    UIButton *btnNext = [inputAccessoryView addButton];
    UIButton *btnDone = [inputAccessoryView addButton];

    [inputAccessoryView setHeight:36];
    [btnNext topInset:0 leftInset:0 bottomInset:0];
    [btnNext rightOffset:0 to:btnDone];
    [btnDone topInset:0 rightInset:0 bottomInset:0];
    [btnNext setWidthEqualTo:btnDone];

    [inputAccessoryView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#DCDFE3"]];

    [btnNext setTitle:@"Next" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnNext setTitleColor:kColorBlack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnDone setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnDone setTitleColor:kColorBlack forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [btnNext addTarget:self action:@selector(keyboardNextClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btnDone addTarget:self action:@selector(keyboardDoneClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return inputAccessoryView;
}
```

Comment: You probably need to set the inputAccessoryView to nil on viewWillDisappear and re-set it on viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear

Comment: What would be the reasoning behind this? Only one view in the app implements the inputAccessoryView, and that view's viewcontroller doesn't go through viewWillDisappear at any point before or during the keyboard-closing process.

Comment: It happened to me once with input view and that solved the problem. Maybe it could be the same with input accessory view. Although i see no reason for such behaviour

Comment: Also you can dismiss keyboard with [self.view endEditing:YES];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In hindsight, the problem was obvious. When creating the input accessory view, I passed the IA view to the keyboard, but didn't store it anywhere myself. So when the keyboard was closed, the IA view got deallocated, thus the crash and error message.

The problem was solved quite simply by saving inputAccessoryView as a property when I first create it.

```
- (UIView *)inputAccessoryView {
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 36);
    _inputAccessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    ...
```

Then it doesn't get deallocated when the keyboard closes, and everything works.